# Виртуальные функции, введение в полиморфизм

Tags: ооп, полиморфизм, c++, функции

Совсем недавно начал изучать книгу Герберта Шилдта "C++, руководство для начинающих" и столкнулся с проблемой. В главе "Применение виртуальных функций" есть пример кода, который у меня, однако, работает неверно.

Вот данный код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class TwoDShape {
    double width;
    double height;
    char name[20];

public:
    TwoDShape() {
        width = height = 0.0;
        strcpy(name, "неизвестный");
    }

    TwoDShape(double w, double h, char *n) {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        strcpy(name, n);
    }

    TwoDShape(double x, char *n) {
        width = height = x;
        strcpy(name, n);
    }

    void showDim() {
        cout << "Ширина и высота равны " <<
                 width << " и " << height << "\n";
    }

    double getWidth() { return width; }
    double getHeight() { return height; }
    void setWidth(double w) { width = w; }
    void setHeight(double h) { height = h; }
    char *getName() { return name; }

    virtual double area() {
        cout << "\nОшибка: функцию area() нужно переопределить.\n";
        return 0.0;
    }
};

class Triangle : public TwoDShape {
    char style[20];
public:
    Triangle() {
        strcpy(style, "неизвестный");
    }

    Triangle(char *str, double w, double h) : TwoDShape(w, h, "треугольник") {
        strcpy(style, str);
    }

    Triangle(double x) : TwoDShape(x, "треугольник") {
        strcpy(style, "равнобедренный");
    }

    double area() {
        return getWidth() * getHeight() / 2;
    }

    void showStyle() {
        cout << "Этот треугольник " << style << "\n";
    }
};

class Rectangle : public TwoDShape {
public:
    Rectangle(double w, double h) : TwoDShape(w, h, "прямоугольник") { }
    Rectangle(double x) : TwoDShape(x, "прямоугольник") { }

    bool isSquare() {
        if (getWidth() == getHeight()) return true;
        return false;
    }

    double area() {
        return getWidth() * getHeight();
    }
};

int main()
{
    TwoDShape *shapes[5];
    shapes[0] = &Triangle("прямоугольный", 8.0, 12.0);
    shapes[1] = &Rectangle(10);
    shapes[2] = &Rectangle(10, 4);
    shapes[3] = &Triangle(7.0);
    shapes[4] = &TwoDShape(10, 20, "общий");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << "Этот объект " << shapes[i]->getName() << "\n";
        cout << "Площадь равна " << shapes[i]->area() << "\n";
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

В книге продемонстрирован такой результат выполнения данной программы:

```
Этот объект треугольник
Площадь равна 48

Этот объект прямоугольник
Площадь равна 100

Этот объект прямоугольник
Площадь равна 40

Этот объект треугольник
Площадь равна 24.5

Этот объект общий
Площадь равна
Ошибка: функцию area() нужно переопределить.
0
```

У меня же выводится следующее:

```
Этот объект общий

Ошибка: функцию area() нужно переопределить.
Площадь равна 0

Этот объект общий

Ошибка: функцию area() нужно переопределить.
Площадь равна 0

Этот объект общий

Ошибка: функцию area() нужно переопределить.
Площадь равна 0

Этот объект общий

Ошибка: функцию area() нужно переопределить.
Площадь равна 0

Этот объект общий

Ошибка: функцию area() нужно переопределить.
Площадь равна 0
```

Кроме того, компилятор выдает предупреждения "taking address of temporary" относительно части кода, в которой происходит инициализация элементов массива указателей на объект TwoDShape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странный какой то код. `main` как минимум нужно переписать так:

```
int main()
{
    TwoDShape *shapes[5];
    shapes[0] = new Triangle("прямоугольный", 8.0, 12.0);
    shapes[1] = new Rectangle(10);
    shapes[2] = new Rectangle(10, 4);
    shapes[3] = new Triangle(7.0);
    shapes[4] = new TwoDShape(10, 20, "общий");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << "Этот объект " << shapes[i]->getName() << "\n";
        cout << "Площадь равна " << shapes[i]->area() << "\n";
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

После этого оно нормально компилируется и выводит такое:

```
Этот объект треугольнипрямоуголь1
Площадь равна 48

Этот объект прямоугольни1
Площадь равна 100

Этот объект прямоугольниA
Площадь равна 40

Этот объект треугольниравнобедре1
Площадь равна 24.5

Этот объект общий

Ошибка: функцию area() нужно переопределить.
Площадь равна 0
```

**Какого кода книжка?**

я бы минимум переписал так код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class TwoDShape {
    double width;
    double height;
    std::string name;

public:
    TwoDShape() : width(0.0), height(0.0), name("неизвестный") {
    }

    TwoDShape(double w, double h, std::string n) : width(w), height(h), name(n) {

    }

    TwoDShape(double x, std::string n)  : width(x), height(x), name(n){
    }

    void showDim() {
        std::cout << "Ширина и высота равны " <<
                 width << " и " << height << std::endl;
    }

    double getWidth() { return width; }
    double getHeight() { return height; }
    void setWidth(double w) { width = w; }
    void setHeight(double h) { height = h; }
    std::string getName() { return name; }

    virtual double area() {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Ошибка: функцию area() нужно переопределить." << std::endl;
        return 0.0;
    }
};

class Triangle : public TwoDShape {
    std::string style;
public:
    Triangle() :style("неизвестный"){
    }

    Triangle(std::string str, double w, double h) : TwoDShape(w, h, "треугольник"), style(str) {
    }

    Triangle(double x) : TwoDShape(x, "треугольник"), style("равнобедренный") {
    }

    double area() {
        return getWidth() * getHeight() / 2;
    }

    void showStyle() {
        std::cout << "Этот треугольник " << style << std::endl;
    }
};

class Rectangle : public TwoDShape {
public:
    Rectangle(double w, double h) : TwoDShape(w, h, "прямоугольник") { }
    Rectangle(double x) : TwoDShape(x, "прямоугольник") { }

    bool isSquare() {
        return getWidth() == getHeight();
    }

    double area() {
        return getWidth() * getHeight();
    }
};

int main()
{
    TwoDShape *shapes[5];
    shapes[0] = new Triangle("прямоугольный", 8.0, 12.0);
    shapes[1] = new Rectangle(10);
    shapes[2] = new Rectangle(10, 4);
    shapes[3] = new Triangle(7.0);
    shapes[4] = new TwoDShape(10, 20, "общий");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << "Этот объект " << shapes[i]->getName() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Площадь равна " << shapes[i]->area() << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    // деструкторы!
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       delete shapes[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Книга 2005 года.

Comment: чувствуется мне, что она переиздана в 2005 на русском. А оригинал древнее.

И я забыл деструкторы повызывать в коде:).

Answer (score 1):

```
shapes[0] = &Triangle("прямоугольный", 8.0, 12.0);
```

Что происходит в этом выражении: 1) создается временный объект, 2) его адрес присваивается shapes[0] 3) временный объект удаляется (хотя сейчас прибегут уточнятели и скажу что это совсем не факт). Именно поэтому компилятор выдает сообщение `taking address of temporary`. По факту, исходя из того что выдает программа, при вызове `shapes[0]->getName()` обращение идёт к объекту `TwoDShape`, т.к. он был создан последним на стеке. Именно поэтому мы видим сообщения от класса `TwoDShape`. Думаю что если в последнюю очередь создать `Triangle` мы будет видеть сообщения от треугольника.

Comment: Да, я делал так и получал сообщения от треугольника.

Comment: я думаю, что это все поведение очень компиляторозависимое. к примеру, gcc 4.7 отказывается компилировать (из-за флага `-fpermissive`), а 4.3 хоть и компилирует, но при запуске программы падает.

Comment: Я тоже так подумал, хотя в книге написано, что, цитирую: "примеры программ работают со всеми компиляторами C++, включая Visual C++".

Comment: @Сергей1991: это потому, что после всех присваиваний по факту на стеке будет лежать только один последний созданный объект, на который будут ссылаться все элементы ``shapes``. Это если говорить про этот конкретный случай, в общем ничего точно сказать нельзя. В любом случае конструкции ``shapes[0] = &Triangle(...)`` не валидны, т.к. после их исполнения в shapes будут лежать адреса объектов которых уже нет.